# Execution plan oddity after re-enabling foreign key constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-execution-plan

I have a weird problem where after setting `nocheck` on a foreign constraint and re-enabling it,

I am getting a same out-dated execution plan that was used with `nocheck` on.

Why would SQL server generate an execution plan as if foreign constraint `FKBtoA` is disabled even after adding the check again with following statement?

```
alter table B check constraint FKBtoA
```

---

**[UPDATE1]**
So far dropping foreign constraint and readding it worked.

```
alter table B drop constraint FKBtoA
alter table B add constraint FKBtoA foreign key (AID) references A(ID)
```

But for really big tables, this seems like an overkill - Is there a better way?

**[ANSWER]**

I had to add `WITH CHECK` in alter statement like following to get the old execution plan

```
alter table B WITH CHECK add constraint FKBtoA foreign key (AID) references A(ID)
```

---

Here is a full SQL statement

```
create table A ( ID int identity primary key )
create table B ( 
    ID int identity primary key,
    AID int not null constraint FKBtoA references A (ID)
)

select  *
from    B
where   exists (select 1 from A where A.ID = B.AID)

alter table B nocheck constraint FKBtoA
GO
select  *
from    B
where   exists (select 1 from A where A.ID = B.AID)

alter table B check constraint FKBtoA
GO
select  *
from    B
where   exists (select 1 from A where A.ID = B.AID)
```

---

Here is the screenshot of execution plans per each `SELECT` statement

Before disabling foreign key constraint
[image]

After disabling foreign key constraint
[image]

After re-enabling foreign key constraint
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely your constraint is enabled but not trusted, so there can be orphan rows in your child table. Read this great post by Hugo Kornelis:[Can you trust your constraints?](https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2007/03/can-you-trust-your-constraints/)

Comment: Ah, ha!  it was "with check" clause that I needed to add in "alter table B add constraint" so it had to be "alter table B WITH CHECK add constraint ..."!  And "sys.check_constraints.is_not_trusted" was set to 1 when I altered constrainted with NOCHECK...

Comment: +1 for "This answer is helpful". i did not know of any such thing as untrusted constraints.

Comment: Here's a good article on the topic - http://explainextended.com/2009/10/15/constraints-and-the-optimizer-in-sql-server-foreign-key/

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be any data in those tables, judging from both the scripts you posted and from the width of the connectors in the plan. Analyzing query plans on empty tables is largely irrelevant: at one single page read, the optimizer will almost certainly choose a full scan.

I assume you're doing this as some sort of experiment, in real world you should join those tables not use inner EXIST.

Comment: Execution plan stayed the same whether the table has any data or not in my case...

Comment: Remus, if the FK constraint is trusted, the optimizer will eliminate a lookup to the parent table, because there always is a parent row.

Comment: right, my answer doesn't really address the OP question, while Alex's answer hits the nail on the head. My general point remains, that plans on empty tables are often completely different from the actual plan used on a populated table. Or in other words, here is a good answer to a different question nobody asked ;)

Comment: @Remus: It was an experiment for some existing much *bigger* stored procedures I had to update and the SQL code I posted was just a small sample of what was actually happening.  Let me play around if having data in tables does change execution plan or not.  Thank you for the a way for me to look a different way to approach my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I do not know, but I know how to rebuild statistics...